# How to validate separate field in group? jQuery validation

Tags: jquery-validate

I have two input fields: `first_name` and `last_name`. I validate them as bellow:

```
rules: {
  required: true,
  maxlength: 50
},
groups : {
      name : "first_name last_name"
    },
    errorElement: "p",
    errorPlacement:  function(error, element) {
      let errorContainer = getErrorContainer(element);
      if($(errorContainer).attr("class") != "error_container") {
        element.parent("div.required").append($('<div class="error_container"></div>'));
        errorContainer = getErrorContainer(element);
      }
      $(errorContainer).append(error);
      function getErrorContainer(element){
          return element.parent("div.required").children("div.error_container");
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      $(element).css("background-color", "#ffd0e0");
      //$(element).css("color", "black");

      $(element).parent("div.required").children("div.error_container").children("p").removeClass("ok").addClass("error");
      $(element).parent("div.required").parent("td").css("background-color", "#ffeded");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
      $(element).css("background-color", "white");

      $(element).parent("div.required").children("div.error_container").children("p").css("display", "block");
      $(element).parent("div.required").children("div.error_container").children("p").removeClass("error").addClass("ok");
      $(element).parent("div.required").children("div.error_container").children("p").html("OK");

      if($(element).parent("div.required").parent("td").children("div.required").children("div.error_container").children("p.error").length == 0){
        $(element).parent("div.required").parent("td").css("background-color", "#fff");
      }
    }
```

Currently, I got a problem that if `first_name` satisfies the rule(ex: maxlength < 50) and `last_name` got error, then the validator always return `ok` status. The reason is: `highlight` and `unhighlight` were activated at the same time, and `unhighlight` overrides `highlight`. I  expect that in this case if I trigger the `last_name` field then validator gives me error status, and if `first_name` ok status. How can I do this? I'm using `jquery-validation 1.19.1`.
*note:* only one error message for name group.

Comment: Why are you using the `groups` method in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the `groups` option for your situation, and based on what you've shown, I think you might have misunderstood the intended purpose of this option.

For example, when using the `require_from_group` method, one would get multiple identical error messages on a set of fields, which is not ideal. The `groups` option solves this problem by showing one error message for this set of fields instead of the duplicate identical messages.

So unless you're using the `require_from_group` or a similar method, you should remove the `groups` option.